# How to build a python package with pre-built .so files

Tags: python, setuptools

I have developed a Python module myself, which relies on multiple pre-built .so files. When I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory containing these .so files, the Python module functions correctly.

Now, my goal is to create a setup script that bundles the Python module and the associated .so files into a single package(I don't want to rebuild the .so files). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can just package them as data files, it's hacky but it works. Make sure you tag the wheel with the appropriate compatibility tags though.

Comment: thank you @wim , that works for me! one more question, if I have a zip file dependency, can I do it the same way? (if I run `export PYTHONPATH=path/to/zip/file:$PYTHONPATH`, it can work )

Comment: Yes, it should work, as long as the file has a .zip extension.